# Anime where the MC uses cudgel

Tags: story-identification, anime, isekai

I remember seeing bits of it many years ago, forgot how many. As I remember it is about a high school boy that was isekaid. He excels in using in cudgels or poles like monkey king's weapon.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Approximately what year would this have been?  Can you describe the character at all, or remember any names?  Who does he fight?

Comment: Since you mentioned the monkey king, do you mean that he has an extending staff like the Ruyi Jingu Bang, or does he just use an ordinary staff?

Comment: @DavidW I saw around Year 2018. Though, I am not sure if the anime was much older. I don't remember any names. All I remember is a scene in which the main character after summoned was was asked what his weapon of choice in which he chose a staff that shocked those who summoned him since they thought it was a terrible weapon. Other of his classmates was also probably summoned (I'm not sure on this one). I would say a merrier version of Arifureta.

Comment: @qazmlpok He uses just an ordinary staff as I can remember.